# git-tf not finding TFS project in VSO

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, git-tf

I have a valid git repository on my local drive that I want to push up into an empty TFS project on VSTS. After configuring (using git-tf configure), every attempt to check-in the code is met with: "git-tf: Could not find a valid TFS Collection at https://mytestvsts.visualstudio.com/MyTestProject".

I'm using the check-in command as follows:

```
$ git-tf checkin --deep --metadata --no-lock --keep-author
```

The username and password have already been saved as part of the configuration and it appears to be connecting okay.

I'm probably missing something simple here...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the URL wrong, just use https://mytestvsts.visualstudio.com. `MyTestProject` refers to the team project.

When you use `git-tf configure`, you should specify the team project in the form of the source control path, ex: `$/MyTestProject`

Also it's worth noting that Git-TF is end-of-life and not being updated; [Git-TFS](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) is actively developed.